# Why do dapp websites ask me to connect to them?

Tags: dapps, nodes, light-clients, browsers

I don't understand why we need to run our own nodes to be using a DApp? Can they just run their own nodes instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **D** in **D**App stands for decentralized application, or more correct: *distributed*.

The idea is simple. Every client runs his own node to verify the blockchain, the smart contracts on it and everyting related to it on its own.

[image: centralized vs. decentralized]

Would they provide their own backend or node, it would simply not be a decentralized app by definition anymore.

This benefits are obvious:

- **trustless**, because you can verify anything on your own
- **unstoppable**, because nobody can turn off your node